# How can I structure my data better in the redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new to this so it might be a very beginner question but I hope there might be a solution to this for the people who are good.

`songData()` here returns an array of lots of song objects.

That's why the `[0]` here in `currentSong: { currentSongData: songData()[0] },`

This is my redux state:

```
const initState = {
  allSongs: songData(),
  currentSong: { currentSongData: songData()[0] },
  isPlaying: false,
  isLibraryOpen: false,
  songTimer: [
    {
      currentTime: 0,
      duration: 0,
    },
  ],
};
```

Whenever I have to access anything in the ***currentSong***, I have to write something like:

```
currentSong.currentSongData.name
```

or if I define the currentSong as `currentSong: [songData()[0]],` then like:

```
currentSong[0].name
```

Is there a better way to define the redux state where I don't have to write such long things when I access the data?

I want to access it by writing

```
currentSong.name
```

BTW this is the structure of the song object.

```
      {
        name: 'Cold Outside',
        cover: 'https://chillhop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/09fb436604242df99f84b9f359acb046e40d2e9e-1024x1024.jpg',
        artist: 'Nymano',
      },
```

Comment: would be better to write songData() result in a variable to avoid unnecessary rerunning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use property spread notation

```
currentSong: { ...songData()[0] }
```

Comment: I would suggest: currentSong: songData()[0]

Comment: I agree, it is much better )

Comment: @AlekseyPolonkaAlex I did that the first time. But I mentioned it above that I had to write ``currentSong[0].name `` to access the name

Answer (score 0):

I would favor to store currentSong's key id which you could extract then its data content from `allSongs`. otherwise, you would be duplicating data something you better avoid. in this way, at initial state you would have `currentSongId: songData()[0].id`

so how would you handle that at your functions? you can use [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector). this function allows you to filter your data so you consume it properly. at your function component you would extract like:

```
// at your component function
const selectedSong = useSelector(state => state.allSongs.filter(({ id }) => id === state.currentSongId))
```

if you read further below at useSelector docs, you could go a step further and memoize its value to avoid unnecessary rerenders in combination with another library [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect).